# How can I specify 0000-00-00 as Year-Month-Date while Save

Tags: magento-1, save, datetime

I want to save a time reference in database which date part should be always `0000-00-00`.

I have below code with me.

```
$entity = Mage::getModel('my_entity_reference')->load(1);
$entity->setCloseTime('0000-00-00 05:05:05');
$entity->save();
```

But this gives me an entry `0000-00-00 00:00:00` for `close_time` column. Please note `close_time` field is of type `DATETIME`.

If I try below code :

```
$entity = Mage::getModel('my_entity_reference')->load(1);
$entity->setCloseTime('2016-09-09 05:05:05');
$entity->save();
```

This gives me a result correctly as `2016-09-09 05:05:05` for the column `close_time`.

This means we cannot use `0000-00-00` as `Y-m-d` while we perform a save. So,

**How can I specify year, month, date as `0000-00-00` in Magento and save it** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is a MySQL validation issue.

Such date `0000-00-00` never existed in our timeline right ?

- 0000 is a valid year
- but 0 isn't a valid month
- and the other 0 isn't a valid day either

A valid date could be: `0000-01-01` for example (I haven't tested it I ain't even sure this would work)

As you don't store real dates, I reckon your best bet would be to change the column type from `DATETIME` to another type like varchar/text.

Comment: **MySQL validation issue** : If this is the case, then direct sql update should not work right ? I tried that and it worked. Secondly, `0000-01-01` worked and that sounds good. I also agree with the solution that you have given (change date type)

Comment: But with datetime, it seems that we cannot save such date `0000-00-00`. Reason is explaining here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27127390

Comment: @RajeevKTomy well yeah this SO answer says the exact same thing as I said `specific date "0000-00-00:00:00:00" is literary impossible and historically incorrect.`

Comment: Yes got it. I thought this is happening due to some internal Magento validations. With this answer and the referenced stackoverflow link, we can conclude that **this is an impossible thing to achieve and Magento is not a culprit** for this Magic.